# Display page number while generating PDF from XML using XSL stylesheet ( Its HTML output )

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Am trying to generate PDF from XML file and i have a table of data which contains near to 100 rows in a table. Am showing only 40 rows per PDF page.
 so, PDF is generating with 3 pages for 100 rows in a table. Also, on each page a showing header and footer also.

Now, am trying to show the Page number on top of every page. Am not sure how to display the page number

Am having the palce holder for the same

```
 <!-- variable ReportHeader-->
<xsl:variable name="ReportHeader">
    <table class="tableReportHeader" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="imglogo" src="image_header.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3 style="color:darkblue; font-family: Arial;">INVOICE</h3>
                <h3 style="color:darkblue; font-family: Arial;">Page : </h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:variable>
```

for example :

```
 Page No : 1/3
 Page No : 2/3
 Page No : 3/3
```

Please find my complete XSL Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:extra-functions">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Invoice</title>
            </head>


                <body>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$ReportHeader"/>

                    <xsl:call-template name="Filler">
                        <xsl:with-param name="fillercount" select="1" />
                    </xsl:call-template>


                    <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderHeader"/>


                    <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderRowsHeader"/>

                    <xsl:for-each select="Order/OrderRows/OrderRow">

                        <table class="tabledetails" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="tdmargin" />
                                <td style="width:70px" align="right" class="blueline">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="ProductID" />
                                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(' ', ' ', '&#160;')"/>
                                </td>

                                <td class="tdmargin" />
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <xsl:if test="(position() mod 40) = 0 ">
                            <!--40 rows per page-->
                            <xsl:call-template name="Filler">
                                <xsl:with-param name="fillercount" select="1" />
                            </xsl:call-template>

                            <xsl:copy-of select="$ReportFooter" />

                            <br class="pagebreak" /> <br />

                            <xsl:copy-of select="$ReportHeader" />



                            <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderRecipient"/>

                            <xsl:call-template name="Filler">
                                <xsl:with-param name="fillercount" select="1" />
                            </xsl:call-template>

                            <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderHeader"/>



                            <xsl:copy-of select="$OrderRowsHeader"/>

                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:copy-of select="$ReportFooter"/>

                </body>
            </html>


        </xsl:template>


    <!-- variable ReportHeader-->
    <xsl:variable name="ReportHeader">
        <table class="tableReportHeader" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img class="imglogo" src="image_header.png" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3 style="color:darkblue; font-family: Arial;">INVOICE</h3>
                    <h3 style="color:darkblue; font-family: Arial;">Page : </h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- variable OrderHeader-->
    <xsl:variable name="OrderHeader">
        <table class="tabledetails" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td class="tdmargin" />
                <th>
                    Order ID:
                </th>

                <td class="tdmargin" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdmargin" />
                <td class="tdorderHeader">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/Data/Order/OrderID" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(' ', ' ', '&#160;')"/>
                </td>

                <td class="tdmargin" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- variable ReportFooter-->
    <xsl:variable name="ReportFooter">
        <table class="tableReportFooter">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20px;"></td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 5pt; text-align: justify;border-top: solid DarkBlue 1px;">
                                One Portals Way, Twin Points WA  98156 Phone: 1-206-555-1417   Fax: 1-206-555-5938
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="width:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--variable OrderRowsHeader-->
    <xsl:variable name="OrderRowsHeader">
        <table class="tabledetails" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout:fixed">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdmargin" />
                <th style="width:70px">
                    Product ID:
                </th>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of package to convert HTML to a PDF? You might want to look at the documentation for that, and see if that contains anything about page numbering.

Comment: No am not using any package. I have XML and XSL stylesheet for parsing.. Using Java code and generating PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well inside of your `for-each` you can calculate the page number, very similar as you do the page break.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="ceiling(position() div  40)"/>
```

This divides the current loop position with the number of items per page. The result is rounded to the next integer value. This way you get `1` from iteration 1 to 40, `2` from iteration 41 to ... you get it.

However to use this value in your `ReportHeader` you have to make the `ReportHeader` a named template and pass the value as parameter to it. Basically the same thing you do with the `Filler`.